# How to include Appendix names in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

My table of contents currently looks like this:

[image]

But I want to change the Appendix and Annex to show the word Appendix and Annex before the letter and Name.

My code looks like this:

```
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5} 
%%\include{cenas}

\PrintBib{myrefs}
%% comment next 2 commands if numbered appendices are not used



\appendix

\include{appendix1}
%%\include{appendix2}
\include{appendix3}


\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\include{annex1}
```

Later one, I did this:

```
\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Annex~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\annex{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
```

But it appear as Appendix on both annex and apeendix

Comment: It would be really helpful (and probably get you an answer faster) if you provided _runnable_ code. A minimal  working example :)

Comment: I don't understand a lot of latex and just using a template, what can i provide more?

Comment: You can check this out: [how to write a minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following helps (unfortunaly there is no minimal working example in the question):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*\annex{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\appendix
\chapter{First Chapter in Appendix}
\chapter{Second Chapter in Appendix}
\annex
\chapter{First Chapter in Annex}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]