# How to add an additional indent to a multiline title in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm modifying the report format in the preamble and I need to indent the following lines (circled in red) of a multi-line title in the table of contents by an additional 0.25" from the first line (hanging indent of 0.25in). From doing [a bit of reading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28343/toc-how-to-no-indent-the-second-line-of-large-entries) it seems like using `\cftchapnumwidth` from `tocloft` may be the answer, but `\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{0.25in}` doesn't seem to change anything. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

[image]

LaTeX code to generate this is:

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaperpaper,]{report}\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing %Double Spacing
\usepackage{sectsty}\allsectionsfont{\normalsize} % Make all font size 12
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left = 1in, right = 1in, top = 1in, bottom = 1in]{geometry}

%Table of Contents, List of Tables, List of Figures
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %Load package for customizing table of contents/lists/figures (Adding titles makes it so that they are formatted the same as chapter titles)
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents} %Rename Contents to Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % dots for chapters in table of contents
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries} %Bold faced normal size font for title of Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries} %Bold faced normal size font for title of List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\normalsize\bfseries} %Bold faced normal size font for List of Tables
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize} %Unbold chapter titles in table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont} %Unbold chapter page numbers in table of contents
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure~} %Precede number with "Figure"
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{2cm} %Add space between figure number and caption
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table~}  %Precede number with "Table"
\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{2cm} %Add space between table number and caption
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0.5in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{1in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{1.5in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\renewcommand{\cftparaindent}{2in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\renewcommand{\cftsubparaindent}{2.5in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from figures in lof
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}  % remove indentation from tables in lot
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{\parskip}  %Spacing between list of table entries
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{\parskip}  %Spacing between list of figure entries

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{0.5in} % Make long titles wrap when they are 0.5 inches away from page numbers
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace} %Prevents gap between chapters in List of Figures
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\noaddvspace} %Prevents gap between chapters in List of Tables

%Chapter Headings
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] %Make chapter number and title on same line
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{} %Adjust title font formatting (normal, bold)
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{40pt}{12pt} %{increases the left margin}{vertical space before the title}{separation between title and text}
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{35pt}{12pt} %{increases the left margin}{vertical space before the title}{separation between title and text}

%Appendix
%\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
%\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2cm}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*\annex{%
  \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435684/how-to-include-appendix-names-in-toc

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6} %Table of contents goes to level 6 headings
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents  % Create List of Tables in Latex
\pagenumbering{roman}

\singlespacing
\listoftables % Create List of Tables in Latex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\newpage

\singlespacing
\listoffigures % Create List of Tables in Latex
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\doublespacing

\hypertarget{a-really-long-heading-so-i-see-what-happens-when-it-takes-up-more-than-one-line-just-in-case-were-getting-crazy}{%
\chapter{A Really Long Heading so I see what happens when it takes up more than one line just in case we're getting crazy}\label{a-really-long-heading-so-i-see-what-happens-when-it-takes-up-more-than-one-line-just-in-case-were-getting-crazy}}

\hypertarget{results}{%
\section{Results}\label{results}}

\hypertarget{a-really-long-heading-so-i-see-what-happens-when-it-takes-up-more-than-one-line-just-in-case-were-getting-crazy-1}{%
\subsection{A Really Long Heading so I see what happens when it takes up more than one line just in case we're getting crazy}\label{a-really-long-heading-so-i-see-what-happens-when-it-takes-up-more-than-one-line-just-in-case-were-getting-crazy-1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve hanging indentation? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, a hanging indent seems to be the name for what I'm trying to do. I'd like the second line of a long entry to be indented an additional 0.25 inches relative to the first line of that entry.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to \end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Your exhibited code has no `\documentclass` or anything that would populate the ToC. Most of the code you showed had nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have added LaTex code that can be compiled to recreate the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response on github that was able to get this working using a combination of `cftXindent`, `\cftXnumwidth` and `\cftXaftersnumb`. Choosing `\cftXnumwidth` requires a bit of trial and error to find values that work for each heading level.

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0.25in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (1)
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}} %hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level 2)

\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0.75in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (2)
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.5cm} %off set hanging indent for long section lines below (level 2)
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}} %hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level 2)

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{1.25in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (3)
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{1.7cm} %off set hanging indent for long section lines below (level 3)
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}}%hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level 3)

\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{1.75in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (4)
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{1.8cm} %off set hanging indent for long section lines below (level 4)
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}}%hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level4)

\renewcommand{\cftparaindent}{2.25in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (5)
\renewcommand{\cftparanumwidth}{2.1cm} %off set hanging indent for long section lines below (level 5)
\renewcommand{\cftparaaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}}%hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level 5)

\renewcommand{\cftsubparaindent}{2.75in} %Set indents to increase by 0.5 inches per level (6)
\renewcommand{\cftsubparanumwidth}{2.4cm} %off set hanging indent for long section lines below (level 6)
\renewcommand{\cftsubparaaftersnumb}{\hspace*{-0.635cm}}%hanging indent for sections that take up more than one line (level 6)

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space} %Have Toc say "Chapter" followed by number 
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm} %Space so caption doesn't overlap "Chapter" number in TOC (added 0.5cm to offset hanging indent)
```